Empty Worksheet_Change event closes Excel
I have several macros on my computer (HP I5 with 8 GB of RAM).
Some macros that use the Worksheet_Change event close Excel.
I took a file from scratch and created a test with a very simple code, where it generates a function to send a MsgBox when a cell value is modified.
If I put a button to execute the function, it works.
If I put the function call through Worksheet_Change of the cell where the value changes, Excel closes.
This is the function (Module1).
Sub Message_Age()
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3") >= 18 Then
        MsgBox "Hello " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3")
    Else
        MsgBox "You are a minor " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3")
    End If
End Sub

I want to run automatically when cell "E3" is changed.
If I change the value it closes Excel.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Target.Address = "$E$3" Then 
        Call Message_Age 
    End If 
End Sub 

My work computer is a Notebook with Windows 10 and Excel 2007.
Excel closes and no message appears.
If the procedure is empty, the same thing happens, Excel closes.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '
    '
End Sub


Is the code in the sheet module of Sheet1?

Are there formulas in cells D3:E3?

there are no formulas... :(

A Worksheet Change: Validate Cell Values
Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    AgeMessage Target
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1 (or the same sheet module)
Main
Sub AgeMessage(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Constants (Name).
    Const NAME_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "D3"
    Const MIN_NAME_LENGTH As Long = 2
    Const MAX_NAME_LENGTH As Long = 31
    ' Constants (Age).
    Const AGE_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "E3"
    Const MIN_AGE As Long = 6
    Const ADULT_AGE As Long = 18
    Const MAX_AGE As Long = 100
    
    Dim ageCell As Range, nameCell As Range, SheetName As String
    
    ' Worksheet and Cells
    With Target.Worksheet
        Set ageCell = .Range(AGE_CELL_ADDRESS)
        Set nameCell = .Range(NAME_CELL_ADDRESS)
        If Intersect(Union(ageCell, nameCell), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        SheetName = .Name
    End With
    
    Dim Value As Variant, Age As Long, UserName As String
    
    ' Name
    Value = nameCell.Value
    If HasValueLengthBetween(Value, MIN_NAME_LENGTH, MAX_NAME_LENGTH) Then
        UserName = Value
    Else
        MsgBox "The name """ & CStr(Value) & """ is invalid." & vbLf & vbLf _
            & "Please enter a name between " & MIN_NAME_LENGTH & " and " _
            & MAX_NAME_LENGTH & " characters long in cell """ _
            & NAME_CELL_ADDRESS & """ of sheet """ & SheetName _
            & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Age
    Value = ageCell.Value
    If IsCellValueIntegerBetween(Value, MIN_AGE, MAX_AGE) Then
        Age = Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter your correct age in cell """ & AGE_CELL_ADDRESS _
            & """ of sheet """ & SheetName & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Message
    Select Case Age
        Case Is < ADULT_AGE ' minor
            MsgBox "Hello, " & UserName & ". You're a minor!", _
                vbExclamation
            Exit Sub ' ???
        Case Is <= MAX_AGE ' adult
            MsgBox "Welcome, " & UserName & ".", _
                vbInformation
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Invalid age """ & Age & """ in 'Select Case'!" _
                & "Recheck the logic!", _
                vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    ' Continue...

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

Help
Function IsCellValueIntegerBetween( _
    Value As Variant, _
    MinInt As Long, _
    MaxInt As Long) _
As Boolean
    ' A number written from a cell into a Variant is always a Double data type.
    ' Also, time is considered a Double while dates and empty cells aren't.
    If VarType(Value) <> vbDouble Then Exit Function ' no number
    If Value <> Int(Value) Then Exit Function ' no integer
    If Value < MinInt Or Value > MaxInt Then Exit Function ' out of bounds
    IsCellValueIntegerBetween = True
End Function

Function HasValueLengthBetween( _
    Value As Variant, _
    MinLen As Long, _
    MaxLen As Long) _
As Boolean
    If IsError(Value) Then Exit Function ' error value
    Dim ValLen As Long: ValLen = Len(Value)
    If ValLen < MinLen Or ValLen > MaxLen Then Exit Function ' out of bounds
    HasValueLengthBetween = True
End Function


Thanks VBasic2008, but my problem is when putting the procedure on Sheet1, Excel automatically closes, without first entering the procedure, regardless of the code you want it to execute.
It's very weird ...  :(
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'
'
'
End Sub
